# Generate shape in three.js from multiple elements

Tags: three.js

Is there a way in three.js to create a poly from multiple individual elements, rectangle for example.

I have attached an example.

I am using:

```
                for(i = 0; i<5; i++){                           


                        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)+1000;

                            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                                color : "#ff"+i+ rand,

                                side : THREE.DoubleSide,
                                transparent : true,
                                opacity : 1
                            });


                            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );


                            if(angle) mesh.rotation.y = angle;


                            mesh.position.set( loop+1, 4,4);

                            scene.add( mesh ); 

                    }
```

When  I apply roatation *mesh.rotation.y = angle;* it doesn't come up with my below design, I rather get a cross + because the panel rotates on it's y from center, not from corner...

Thank you

The [image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to achieve what you're trying to do. The problem you are facing stems from transform origin, as you noted, origin defaults to position [0,0,0]. So, your options are:

- build a transform matrix using a different transform offset for rotation, this is probably an overkill for simple use-cases.
- translate geometry to not be centered on [0,0,0], for example you can move the whole quad (your geometry) right so that the left edge of the quad aligns with [0,0,0], then, when you rotate, left edge will stay put.
- embed Mesh inside a Group, rotate the Mesh and translate (position.set(....)) the Group.

no matter which route you take - you will still have to deal with the some trigonometry as you will need to compute the position for the next segment to align with the edge of the previous one.

One more way around that is to build the following type of structure

```
Group[ 
   Mesh 1, 
   Mesh 2, 
   Mesh 3, 
   Group [
     Mesh 4,
     Mesh 5,
     Mesh 6,
     Group [
        Mesh 7
     ]
   ]
]
```

Last group is unnecessary, it's there purely for consistency.

As far as the trigonometry that I mentioned - it's simple Sin and Cos stuff, so it should be quite simple. Here is some pseudo-code that you'll need:

```
prevPosition, prevAngle //position and angle of previous segment
// Compute next segment transform
nextPosition.x = Math.cos(prevAngle)*segmentSize + prevPosition.x;
nextPosition.z = Math.sin(prevAngle)*segmentSize + prevPosition.z;
```

Comment: Thank you @travnik, but I am afraid it's too much for my knowledge. I have done the following code, but it outputs only 3 shapes. I have to learn more about groupping meshes. https://pastebin.com/xyHyTRYq. Can you point me that is wrong in the code? Thank you.